# String has the same value repeated after space

Tags: php

I need to remove the duplicate, don't know how to call it exactly

```
$string = "this is a sample this is a sample"
```

As you can see there is "**this is a sample**" twice in a single string. I have many strings like that (with of course different text, which is then repeated again) and I need to bulk remove the duplicate text, but don't have any idea how to do this.
The result I want is:

```
$string = "this is a sample"
```

Comment: Is it only **one** phrase repeated `n` times that you want only once? What if you have `$string = "this is a sample this is a sample this"`, what is the priority?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Detect Duplicate Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643452/php-detect-duplicate-text)

Comment: `I have many strings like that (with of course different text,)` please provide all possible format of string so that you can get a more generic solution, because the solutions given right now will work in the given scenario not in any other scenario.

Comment: @siniradam not a duplicate, I think. In that question OP wanted to detect if there was text repetition. Here, OP wants (if I understood correctly) to get N repetitions of a phrase and make it one.

Comment: @ishegg I see, although may not be the exactly duplicate but needed answer can be found there in my opinion.

Comment: Is it possible that you also have a sentence repeated more then once in a phrase? Can it be something like this: "_this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample ..._"?

Comment: It is only one phrase repeated. It is only one duplicate, doesn't occur more than 3 times same sentence in one string, for example:
`Super Durable Phone Video Super Durable Phone Video`
`Get All The Info You Need Get All The Info You Need`
And there is no other text in that string, so as someone gave answer substr by half may work, but I have 300k of records in db and not every string is like that (some are ok) and now I have to check if it really contains a duplicate.

Comment: Well nevermind I think I got it. I will just do a substr by half get the first half, then second half, trim and compare them, if equal then remove one half, original = the other half, save to db. Thank you everyone

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment, because you didn't tagged my user name with "@" in it. If you still have difficulties, having in mind the 330K records and an eventual words/chars asymmetry, then let us know. Good luck.

Comment: @aendeerei I worked it out :) didn't tag because I would have to tag each one of you, and if I tag two or more people I don't think a notification goes to you

Comment: Well, then it's all perfect :-) Good luck further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $text = "this is a sample this is a sample";
    echo $splitstring1 = substr($text, 0, floor(strlen($text) / 2));
?>
```

I hope it can help you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe?

```
echo substr($string, ceil(strlen($string)/2));
```